# Unable to run .net core 2.2 api application :No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, role-base-authorization

We are integrating Azure Active Directory with React web application and backend would be .net core 2.2 API.

Current Status: we could able to add app registration for React web application into Azure AD. With that, we could able to do authentication and getting Bearer token after successful authentication on react web app.

Challenges I’m facing:  Since authentication is done, I would like to perform **Authorization** at Backend .net core API with use of Bearer token. However, I couldn’t get success as I keep getting the following error.

**InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.**  Could anyone help to resolve this issue?

Code snippet from .net core api project:

in startup file: ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method.

```
              services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole",
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.AddRequirements(new AdminRequirement());
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireRole("Admin");

                });
        });

  services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AdminHandler>();
```

In Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env):

```
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
```

And AuthenticationHandler:

```
    public class AdminHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdminRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminRequirement requirement)
    {
        //Check user claims for Role
        if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to specify the schema, maybe due to different kind of authentication you should add in the Configure() method this code:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            IEnumerable<string> schemes = GetSchemesForRequest(context);
            foreach (string scheme in schemes)
            {
                AuthenticateResult result = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                    continue;

                context.User = result.Principal;
                break;
            }
            await next();
        });
```

Then in your method:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetSchemesForRequest(HttpContext context)
```

you can think what is the proper scheme for that request.